$f_{V \mid W}$ in terms of $f_{U \mid W}$
the task: Let $U$ be a continuously distributed random variable, $W$ be another random variable that is different from $U$, and $R \sim$ Rademacher(0.5), i.e., $R= \pm 1$ with equal probability. Assume that $R$ is independent of $(U, W)$.
(a) Find the mean and variance of $V=R \cdot U$. Suppose that $\mathrm{E}(U)=\mu_U$ and $\mathrm{V}(U)=\sigma_U^2$.
(b) Find $f_{V \mid W}$ in terms of $f_{U \mid W}$.
I have done point A. got E(V)=E(R)*E(U)=$0*\mu_U=0$ and var(V)=E(R$^2$)*E(U$^2$)=$\mu_U^2*\sigma_U^2$
But I do not understand how to do point B. So I thought V=R*U and R=+-1 so V is either -U or U with equal probability.
Is it true $f_{V|W} = P(V = v|W = w) = P(RU = v|W = w) = P(U = v, R = 1|W = w) + P(U = -v, R = -1|W = w)$
How do I do it next, I am lost?

You are on the right track. Did you use the independence of $R$ and $W$? Also, $\text{Var}(V) = \mu_U^2 + \sigma_U^2$, not the product.

@sudeep5221 thanks, I mistyped * instead of +. Also am I correct that for b the answer would be  $f_{V|W}(v|w) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot [f_{U|W}(v|w) + f_{U|W}(-v|w)]$? Thanks in advance.

Yes, that's correct.
